# I can't make the bot write that you don't have rights to use the command

Tags: discord.py

I created a lot of moderation commands, and only allowed admins to use them.I also really want to make such a scheme:If a person who does not have the right to use the command writes it,the bot sends a message that you do not have the right to use this command.Please help me figure this out!

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def ban(ctx,member:discord.Member,reason):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="ban",color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина',value=reason,inline=False)
    await member.ban()
    await channel.send(embed = emb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling).

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def ban(ctx,member:discord.Member,reason):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="ban",color=0xff0000)
    emb.add_field(name='Модератор',value=ctx.message.author.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Нарушитель',value=member.mention,inline=False)
    emb.add_field(name='Причина',value=reason,inline=False)
    await member.ban()
    await channel.send(embed = emb)

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You do not have the required permissions to use this command.')
```